# Overriding an existing style in the android sdk

Tags: android

I would like to override the following style existing in the android sdk in res\values\styles.xml:

```
   <style name="Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText" parent="Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    </style>
```

by the following

```
   <style name="Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText" parent="Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">3</item>
    </style>
```

I tried replacing the second code in **res/value/styles.xml** but it didn't work.

I do appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="@android:Widget.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">3</item>
</style>
```

Note that you have to add the 'android' namspace in front of a style from the framework. So change  `parent="Widget.ActionBar.TabText"`  to  `parent="@android:Widget.ActionBar.TabText"`.

Comment: I don't think it's working, unless this is not the style to change the  font to lower case in the tabs ( I'm using navigation tabs )

Comment: yes i did this.. and not changing the style. merci ktir abo 7med 3am 3azbak :)

Comment: `merci ktir abo 7med 3am 3azbak` wait what?

Comment: but the question is how will the application know that i want to use this style? will it override automatically just when i add them to the styles.xml ? Or should I call "MyStyle" from the Manifest file just like we do for android:theme = "@style/AppTheme"

Comment: Oh haha :P Are you actually overriding this in the sdk? Or is it in *your* values folder?

Comment: im overriding this in the sdk but from my values folder